# php wamp; forbidden folder in www

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am using wamp and am creating a uLogin PHP Authentication Library(http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/). I have access to phpmyadmin, the local host seems to work, phpinfo() runs, everything on there seems to be working.

The problem is the c:/wamp/www/ulogin is giving me a forbidden 403 in the console. The error log for apache(2.4.9) is giving me AH01797: client denied by server configuration: My windows event log is giving me: an attempt was made to query the existence of a blank password for an account.

Is this a prblem with the wamp set up in apache or in the mysql setup; or both? I have run other php programs via www; this is the first time I ran into this problem.
I have researched this extensively and found a lot of the same answer, but it was for older versions of the program. Also, while developing on the localhost I can allow to all, I would prefer just to set it up as if the website was live.

Comment: Have you checked your apache config? Sounds like you ain't got the rights to access the above Path/Location. Check your apache config for /wamp/www/ulogin if you have this one set up or any path above that (up to / or C:\), look out for *Order* and *Allow from*.

Comment: <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks           AllowOverride all                      Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: Any directory-entries for /wamp/www/ulogin? Have you checked whether th 403 comes from you apache or from ulogin? Add some debug message to the ulogin index (or whatever gets called).

Comment: no I have not put /www/ulogin in anything. I left the default wamp/www/

Comment: and the 403 is in the apache error log

Comment: it is in the apache. I changed the root in the ulogin main.cofig folder. if it was the ulogin i should have got a not found error but I still got the 403

Comment: but my other php modules run fine. Idk what it is.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess in your ulogin directory or above?

Comment: yea in both. in ulogin it says deny from all. I changed it to allow from all and the 403 disappeared. Thanks man I think that did it.

Comment: Alright, I made it an "official answer". You should check the ulogin docs on WHY there is a *deny from all* before stripping that (and using that setting in production).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to check what's wrong:

1) Check your apache config: Check Directory-entries for your target directory and above. Look out for *Order* and *Allow from* (or *Require* for 2.4+)

2) Check whether there are any *.htaccess* files in your target directory or above. Again, look out for *Allow* / *Deny* and *Require*.

3) Check if the 403 is emitted by apache or your application: Add some debug message at the very top of your application logic (commonly some sort of index.php).